# How to get offset for RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android

I want to save the position of my RecyclerView, then reset it later. If the top item is only halfway visible, what do I use to save this offset?

For the position I am using:
findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()

To reset the position I am using:

```
        ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, offset);
```

But I am not sure what to pass as the offset?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You must use `LinearLayoutManager` as this..

```
LinearLayoutManager manager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
int position = manager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
View firstItemView = manager.findViewByPosition(position);
float Offset = firstItemView.getTop();
```

And get the position and offset of first item in current window.